# Django filter all items within bounding box (by LAT, LNG)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, geometry, coordinates

I use `Postgres` with `Django` and I have a model `Parcel` that has coordinate fields:

```
address_lat = models.DecimalField...
address_lat = models.DecimalField...
```

I'm trying to create a method (on Manager) that returns all parcels withing the given area in km. I don't use `Postgis` and `GeoDjango` so it doesn't need to be within circle, it can be a square. So I did this:

```
def get_bounding_box(lat, lng, km):

    lat_change = Decimal(km / 111.2)
    lng_change = Decimal(abs(math.cos(lat * (Decimal(math.pi) / Decimal(180)))))
    bounds = {
        'lat_min': lat - lat_change,
        'lng_min': lng - lng_change,
        'lat_max': lat + lat_change,
        'lng_max': lng + lng_change
    }
    return bounds


class ParcelManager(models.Manager):
    def within_area(self, lat, lng, km):
        bounding_box = get_bounding_box(lat, lng, km)
        return self.get_queryset().filter(address_lat__gte=bounding_box['lat_min'],
                                          address_lng__gte=bounding_box['lng_min'],
                                          address_lat__lte=bounding_box['lat_max'],
                                          address_lng__lte=bounding_box['lng_max'],
                                          )
```

The problem is that this returns too much parcels. For 5cm input (0.00005) it returns two parcels, one of them is the same parcel but the other is almost 1km away.

```
In [1]: p = Parcel.objects.last()

In [2]: p.address_lat
Out[2]: Decimal('34.784954778041')

In [3]: p.address_lng
Out[3]: Decimal('-92.250170096711')

In [4]: Parcel.objects.within_area(p.address_lat,p.address_lng,0.00005)
Out[4]: <QuerySet [<Parcel: Parcel object (42173)>, <Parcel: Parcel object (51764)>]>

In [5]: results = Parcel.objects.within_area(p.address_lat,p.address_lng,0.00005)

In [6]: results.first().address_lat
Out[6]: Decimal('34.784954911726')

In [7]: results.first().address_lng
Out[7]: Decimal('-92.286596972046')
```

Do you know where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have computed a factor taking into consideration the latitude, but you forgot to them apply your buffer distance.

```
lng_change = Decimal(km / 111.2) * Decimal(abs(math.cos(lat * (Decimal(math.pi) / Decimal(180)))))
```

Comment: PS: using PostGIS would remove all/most these errors and hassle...

Comment: This is the only thing where I need such computations, do you think it's worth to install the PostGis/GeoDjango just for this purpose? (The project is in production already)